# How to return a PHP echo to HTML audio src

Tags: php, html, ajax

How would I return the value that's output by my PHP file? I've tried a few different ways like PHP each in the source but I could never get a working return.

PHP

```
<?php

$f_contents = file("/var/www/html/scripts/songs.index");
$line = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)];
$data = $line;

/** print the contents of the names array */
echo($data);

?>
```

Example of the PHP files return:

```
/var/www/html/uploads/Music/My_Life_NF_Perception_2017.mp3
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<?php include "radio.php" ?>
</head>

<audio controls>
<source src="<?php echo $data; ?>"  type="audio/mp3">
</audio><br />
</html>
```

Comment: In your PHP file: do you mean that you want to return a random song from `songs.index` file?

Comment: The php file does what i want. it returns the file path from songs.index to $data. I just need to figure out how to output data which is the link to a random song into the src in the html file so audio knows what to play.

Comment: In your HTML file, do you call your PHP file?

Comment: I've tried a couple ways I found online. Unsuccessfully.

Comment: If you are not calling your PHP file then your variable `$data` that you are trying to print in your HTML file is not defined.

At the top of your HTML file before your `<html>` tag, add this `<?php include "yourfile.php" ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out.

I had to change the HTML to:

```
<audio controls>
        <source id="source" src="" type="audio/mp3">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            data: { attr1: 'value1' },
            success: function( data ) {
                console.log(data);
                $('audio #source').attr('src', data);
                $('audio').get(0).load();
                $('audio').get(0).play();
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Lastly, I also had an issue in my index file. Instead of pointing from the root it needed to point from current folder so I removed the first few directories and it now looks like:

```
/uploads/Music/My_Life_NF_Perception_2017.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
explode("/",$data);
```

and get after uploads/Music/My_Life_NF_Perception_2017.mp3